# Angular cli mathjax

Tags: angular, mathjax

Angular 4.0 npm install mathjax for node_module, add `"scripts": ["./node_modules/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"],  to angular-cli.json and add`types": ["mathjax"],` to tsconfig.app.json

but error say "MathZoom.js and MathMenu.js not found".
How to deal with this problem......
thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To add MathJax into Angular 4 application, simply add the below lines in index.html and do the following steps.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML"></script>
<!-- MathJax Implementation -->
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
         showProcessingMessages: false,
         tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\(','\\)']] }
        });
    </script>
```

HTML code where you want to render the formula

```
<div class="mathjax" >{{Formula}}</div>
```

TS file where you want to apply mathjax

```
let mathjax=document.getElementsByClassName('mathjax');
       eval('MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, mathjax])');
      eval('MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, mathjax])');
```

Comment: Hi, friend ! I think your answer is how to use on JavaScript, but I want to know is how to use on angular cli project ? thanks ! @Prithivi Raj

Comment: I am also using the same procedure for angular CLI and ionic CLI projects and they are working fine. you can also do it by npm install but it's more simple I guess